# 何も means 'Nothing' instead of 'What also'

Tags: grammar, words

I recently learnt that 「何も」 means 'nothing' (e.g. 「何も怖くないです。」 means 'Nothing scares (me).').

But how do I say 'What else'? (e.g. 'What else goes well with this dress?' or 'What else never dies?)

Comment: Do you mean the "also" as in "The God never dies, and what _also_ never dies?", or in "What never defeats and _also_ never dies?" They are different things.

Comment: @broccoliforest I mean "The God never dies, and what also never dies?" sort of 'also' but it'd be nice to know both (but I might have to make a new question for that to avoid confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with "他に"
'What also goes well with this dress?'→このドレスに合うものは**他に**何がある？
'What also never dies?→死なないのは、**他に**何がある？
As mentioned in a comment above, this is more of a "what else" as opposed to a "what also."

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see what you're asking. The particle も can indeed be used in a similar manner to the English *also*, e.g. 子供｛こども｝の時｛とき｝、あまりゲームをしなかった。　今**も**ゲームをしない (When I was a child, I didn't really play games. I also don't really play games now). But there isn't really a way to contract *also* into 何 in the same manner of 何も (nothing) 何か (something).

If you wish to say *also*, as in, "Also, what will we eat?", where *also* is being used as a conjunction, you would use 「また」. For example: **また**、何を食{た}べる？

If you wish to use *also* to mean, "In addition to" or "additionally" or "furthermore", you would use さらに instead of また. さらに is a bit more challenging to use because さらに often requires you to change certain particles to も, for example  さらに、水**も**　飲みたいです instead of さらに、水**を**　飲みたいです.

Comment: Alex's answer was what I was looking for, but this is definitely useful to know.

Comment: @Teco Why don't you upvote this answer, too, then ;)

Comment: Alright, now they can.